# Group memberships based on custom schema?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have read about adding custom attributes to our domain schema.  Is there any way to base group membership on this custom schema data?  i.e. have a user be added to a group automatically if they have a certain custom attribute flag, or any particular schema data for that matter, similar to the way you can add all users of a domain to a group.  I guess it would be the same or similar to dynamic groups in LDAP.

Comment: I believe this would be possible although I've never tried it. You'd have to pull the details for the Directory Profiles and then move them into or out of groups based on the existence of the custom schema.